Odoo-15 Controller not redirecting
In this controller after correct login the controller should redirect me to the dashboard, but its not working for some reason, there is no error message or traceback
 @http.route('/login/process', type='http', auth='public', methods=['POST'], website=True, csrf=False)
    def login_process(self, **post):
        email = post.get('email')
        password = post.get('password')
        db = request.env.cr.dbname

        try:
            user = request.env['res.users'].sudo().search([('login', '=', email)])
            if user and user.password == hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest():
                uid = user.id
                request.session.authenticate(db, email, password)  
                print("**********************************")  
                return redirect('/') 
            else:
                raise ValidationError('Invalid email or password')

        except ValidationError as e:
            return http.request.render('test.test_view_form', {'error': str(e)})

I have tried overriding the whole res.users authenticate method and its still not working  and also there is no error message or traceback

Have you tried return request.redirect('/') ?
